# how to solve cannot allocate memory in static TLS block error for python packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, oserror

I am using ubuntu `20.04` and conda `4.8.3`. I have installed a package in one of my environments using `pip` (`pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir gmsh-dev`) but when I try to import the package in a jupyter notebook, I face the following error:

```
OSError: /home/alid/miniconda3/envs/new_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gmsh-git-Linux64-sdk/lib/libgmsh.so: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
```

I have no idea what is my problem and do appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [how others solved similar problems](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/sklearn-cannot-allocate-memory-in-static-tls-block/158954), try adding it to `LD_PRELOAD`.

```bash
## set the env var for "new_env" environment
conda env config vars set -n new_env LD_PRELOAD='/home/alid/miniconda3/envs/new_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gmsh-git-Linux64-sdk/lib/libgmsh.so'

## test importing
conda run -n new_env python -c "import gmsh"
```

See [the documentation on managing environment variables in Conda envs](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables).

Comment: Dear @merv, Firstly, I do appreciate you for devoting time to my issue. I tried your first line of code and after it when I run `jupyter notebook` in my terminal I face the following error:  `/home/alid/miniconda3/envs/new_env/bin/python: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /home/alid/miniconda3/envs/new_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gmsh-git-Linux64-sdk/lib/libgmsh.so)`.

Comment: @Ali_d seems like a new problem and worth a new question